# Tradingview pine script strategy - entering and closing on every bar?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

As title - this strategy is entering and closing on every single bar, while I want it to only open on the first bar that meets `entryLong/entryShort` criteria, then remain in the position until `exitLong/exitShort` conditions are met.

```
//@version=5
strategy("test", overlay = false, process_orders_on_close=true)

// Input
Period1 = input(7, title = "Period1")
Period1 = input(14, title = "Period2")

// Calculate Stochastics
stoch1 = ta.stoch(close, Period1)
stoch2 = ta.stoch(close, Period2)

// Variables
var bool entered = false

// Count positive/negative CCIs
positiveStoch = (stoch1 > 0 ? 1 : 0) + (stoch2 > 0 ? 1 : 0)
negativeStoch = (stoch1 < 0 ? 1 : 0) + (stoch2 < 0 ? 1 : 0)

// Entry conditions
entryLong = positiveStoch >= 2
entryShort = negativeStoch >= 2

// Exit condition
exitLong = positiveStoch <= 1
exitShort = negativeStoch <= 1


// Variables
var bool entered = false

// Entry and exit logic
if entryLong and not entered
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    entered := true

else if entryShort and not entered
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short) 
    entered := true 
    
if (exitLong or exitShort)
    strategy.close("Long")
    strategy.close("Short")
    entered := false
```

How do I fix this?

**Corrected code for future Googlers, thanks to vitruvius**

**Basically split up the exit logic, and keep separate tracking for long and short positions.**

```
// Variables
var bool enteredLong = false
var bool enteredShort = false

// Entry and exit logic
if entryLong and not enteredLong
    if enteredShort
        strategy.close("Short")
        enteredShort := false
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    enteredLong := true

if entryShort and not enteredShort
    if enteredLong
        strategy.close("Long")
        enteredLong := false
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short) 
    enteredShort := true 
    
if enteredLong and exitLong
    strategy.close("Long")
    enteredLong := false

if enteredShort and exitShort
    strategy.close("Short")
    enteredShort := false
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @vitruvius edited code to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if the stoch is positive or negative but the stoch never goes negative. Therefore, `positiveStoch` is always `2` and `negativeStoch` is always `0`.

Due to that, `entryLong = positiveStoch >= 2` is always `true` and `exitShort = negativeStoch <= 1` is always `true`.

Due to that, you enter a trade every second bar and close it on the next bar because you close orders with `(exitLong or exitShort)` condition.

You need to fix your logic and potentially close longs only with `exitLong` and shorts only with `exitShort` and **not** `or` them.